# Number of trials required for chance of 1 success to be greater than x

Tags: probability

I have a question regarding binomial probability:

A person is firing a bow at a target, and has a 25% chance of success.  How many times must they fire so that the probability of hitting the target at least once is greater than 2/3?

How do you work this out?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: This is the same as the probability that he does not hit the target at all is less than $1\over{3}$

Comment: I think you forgot the "homework" tag. If probability of success is $p$, then prob of failure is $(1-p)$, and prob of $n$ successive failures is $(1-p)^n$. So prob of success at least once among $n$ trials is $1-(1-p)^n$. Plug in your numbers appropriately, and  jiggle the algebra around to solve for $n$.

Comment: @JohnForkosh the homework tag has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that$$P(\text{hits target at least once})\geq \frac{2}{3}$$ is the same as $$1-P(\text{doesn't hit the target at all})\geq \frac{2}{3}$$
Then it follows that $$1-{n\choose{0}}\cdot{\frac{3}{4}^n}\geq\frac{2}{3}$$
And so

$$\frac{3}{4}^n\leq\frac{1}{3}$$

So $n$ must be at least $\approx 3.8188$.

We cannot shoot a target $3.8188$ times so we get $n=4$. Checking,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{4} {n\choose{k}}{\frac{1}{4}}^k \cdot {\frac{3}{4}}^{n-k}=0.6835938\geq \frac{2}{3}$$